# Allow/Disallow app to Access the Network

Tags: ios, iphone, firewall

I want to build an app for iPhone that allow/disallow other installed apps to access the network, data transfer etc.(like firewall). Is it possible to make such an app. If so how can I make, which libraries should I use.
Thanks

Comment: I guess it is not possible in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Each application is installed on a sandbox environment, you can't access the data of other apps or block it's features.

Apple won't allow this. If you do so, it's against the Apple's App-store policy.